# Why are multiple if statements faster than executing a while loop?

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, performance-testing

My program's input is a large string, around 30,000 characters. Below is the code for my own strlen:

```
size_t  strlen(const char *c)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (c[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}
```

The version of strlen above takes ~2.1 seconds to execute. Through a different version, I was able to achieve ~1.4 seconds.

My question is, why are multiple if statements faster than executing a while loop?

```
size_t  strlen(const char *str)
{
    const char  *start;

    start = str;
    while (1)
    {
        if (str[0] == '\0')
            return (str - start);
        if (str[1] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 1);
        if (str[2] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 2);
        if (str[3] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 3);
        if (str[4] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 4);
        if (str[5] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 5);
        if (str[6] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 6);
        if (str[7] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 7);
        if (str[8] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 8);
        str += 9; // 
    }
}
```

My question is, why, that alot of if statements, is faster then still running a loop?

Edit: With stantard lib, is something around 1.25 secs.

Comment: Because you forgot to compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: 1) Check your optimisation settings, 2) Examine the output assembly, 3) We need a decent statistical test which includes how you measured the execution time. 4) Out of interest, does the standard library beat both times (it ought to)?

Comment: Yes. Stantard lib was like 1.25 to run.

Comment: You should make `i` a `size_t`. This might or might not change the performance, but will at least ensure better portability and conformity on long strings.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you benchmark? It is surprising that your naive unrolled loop perform almost as good as the libc implementation.

Comment: Can you also describe your environment: C compiler and options, OS and version?

Comment: Some 90% of these kind of questions can be answered with incorrect benchmarking. The fact that you don't even mention compiler and optimization settings suggests that this is yet another post like that.

Comment: What you've done is *loop unrolling*. GCC can be made to unroll the first example with `-funroll-all-loops`

Comment: I find 2.1 and 1.4 seconds on 30k characters very hard to believe. (On a regular machine, that's tens of thousands of cycles per character.) Did you forget to terminate your string?

Comment: @molbdnilo That's a good point. I didn't spot that.

Comment: Guys, its a university code. My program isnt ONLY strlen, but part of them i use alot of times strlen. So thats why 2 seconds, to run all program. With that two different strlen, that was the difference

Comment: Basically the project is get next line. i will open a file .txt, with file descriptor / buff_size 1 run the program and get next line until finish. thats all project and why was 2 seconds

Comment: I don't care what kind of code it is. We need to see how you measure. Why are you not supplying them?

Comment: @rogertaht So when you wrote "The version of strlen above takes ~2.1 seconds to execute", that was not actually true?

Comment: @Bathsheba https://pastebin.com/njKARLse  i dont run opmizations, just run gcc with files. No flags.

I know strlen isnt the long thing that affect the program, but i run 5 times with each approach and that was the average

Objective isnt optimizate that, just understand why that happened.

Comment: Now you've let the cat out of the bag. File I/O time is order of magnitudes slower than either `strlen` you supply. All the difference is explainable by your OS and how it handles File I/O.

Comment: @molbdnilo 
My program run in 2.1 seconds with first strlen.   
My program run in 1.4 with second strlen.
My program run in 1.25 with lib strlen

5 times with each, that was average

Comment: I used at least 3 times strlen per function call.

Comment: Even your pastebin sample does not provide enough information: the header files are missing and the definition of `get_next_line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pertinent, but your benchmark is incomplete and has surprising results.

Here is a modified and instrumented version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define VERSION     3
#define TRIALS      100
#define ITERATIONS  100

#if VERSION == 1

size_t strlen1(const char *c) {
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (c[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    return (i);
}
#define strlen(s)  strlen1(s)

#elif VERSION == 2

size_t strlen2(const char *str) {
    const char  *start;

    start = str;
    while (1) {
        if (str[0] == '\0')
            return (str - start);
        if (str[1] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 1);
        if (str[2] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 2);
        if (str[3] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 3);
        if (str[4] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 4);
        if (str[5] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 5);
        if (str[6] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 6);
        if (str[7] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 7);
        if (str[8] == '\0')
            return (str - start + 8);
        str += 9;
    }
}
#define strlen(s)  strlen2(s)

#elif VERSION == 3

size_t strlen3(const char *str) {
    const uint64_t *px, sub = 0x0101010101010101, mask = 0x8080808080808080;
    const char *p;

    for (p = str; (uintptr_t)p & 7; p++) {
        if (!*p)
            return p - str;
    }
    for (px = (const uint64_t *)(uintptr_t)p;;) {
        uint64_t x = *px++;
        if (((x - sub) & ~x) & mask)
            break;
    }
    for (p = (const char *)(px - 1); *p; p++)
        continue;
    return p - str;
}
#define strlen(s)  strlen3(s)

#endif

int get_next_line(int fd, char **pp) {
    char buf[32768];
    char *line = NULL, *new_line;
    char *p;
    ssize_t line_size = 0;
    ssize_t nread, chunk;

    while ((nread = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0) {
        p = memchr(buf, '\n', nread);
        chunk = (p == NULL) ? nread : p - buf;
        new_line = realloc(line, line_size + chunk + 1);
        if (!new_line) {
            free(line);
            *pp = NULL;
            return 0;
        }
        line = new_line;
        memcpy(line + line_size, buf, chunk);
        line_size += chunk;
        line[line_size] = '\0';
        if (p != NULL) {
            lseek(fd, chunk + 1 - nread, SEEK_CUR);
            break;
        }
    }
    *pp = line;
    return line != NULL;
}

int main() {
    char *line = NULL;
    int fd, fd2, count, trial;
    clock_t min_clock = 0;

    fd = open("one_big_fat_line.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("cannot open one_big_fat_line.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fd2 = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
    if (fd2 < 0) {
        printf("cannot open output.txt\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (trial = 0; trial < TRIALS; trial++) {
        clock_t t = clock();
        for (count = 0; count < ITERATIONS; count++) {
            lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            lseek(fd2, 0L, SEEK_SET);
            while (get_next_line(fd, &line) == 1) {
                write(fd2, line, strlen(line));
                write(fd2, "\n", 1);
                free(line);
            }
        }
        t = clock() - t;
        if (min_clock == 0 || min_clock > t)
            min_clock = t;
    }
    close(fd);
    close(fd2);

    double time_taken = (double)min_clock / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Version %d time: %.3f microseconds\n", VERSION, time_taken * 1000000 / ITERATIONS);
    return 0;
}
```

The program opens a file, reads lines from it with a custom function `read_next_line()` that uses unix system calls and `malloc` to return arbitrary sized lines. It then writes these lines using the unix system call `write` and appends a newline with a separate system call.

Benchmarking this sequence with your test file, a 30000 byte file with a single line of ASCII characters, shows a very different performance from what you measure: depending on the selected implementation of `strlen` and the compilation optimisation settings, the time on my laptop range from 15 microseconds to 82 microseconds per iteration, nowhere close to 1 or 2 seconds as you observe.

- Using the C library default implementation, I get 14.5 microseconds per iteration with or without optimisations.
- Using your `strlen1` naive implementation, I get 82 microseconds with optimisations disabled and 25 microseconds with `-O3` optimisations.
- Using your `strlen2` unrolled implementation, the speed improves to 30 microseconds with `-O0` and 20 microseconds with `-O3`.
- Finally, a more advanced C implementation reading 8 bytes at a time `strlen3` provides further improved performance at 21 microseconds with `-O0` and 15.5 microseconds with `-O3`.

Note how compiler optimisations affect the performance much more than manual optimisations.

The reason your unrolled version performs better is the generated code increments the pointer once per byte and an unconditional jump is performed once per byte, whereas the unrolled version reduces these to once every 9 bytes.  Note however that the C compiler gets almost the same performance with `-O3` on the naive code as what you get unrolling the loop yourself.

The advanced version is very close in performance to the C library implementation, which may use assembly language with SIMD instructions. It reads 8 bytes at a time and performs an arithmetic trick to detect if any of these bytes has its topmost bit changed from `0` to `1` when subtracting `1` from its value. The extra initial steps are required to align the pointer to read 64-bit words, thus avoiding unaligned reads that have undefined behavior on some architectures. It also assumes that memory protection is not available at the byte level. On modern x86 systems, memory protection has a 4K or larger granularity, but some other systems such as Windows 2.x the protection was much finer grained, preventing this optimisation altogether.

Note however that the benchmark also measures the time to read from the input file, locate the newline and write to the output file. The relative performance of `strlen` and `strlen3` are probably much more significant. Indeed a separate benchmark for just `strlen(line)` with your 30000 byte line shows a time of 2.2 microseconds for `strlen3()` and 0.85 microseconds for `strlen()`.

Conclusions:

- benchmarking is a tricky game.
- compilers are good at optimizing when told to do so, `-O3` is a good default.
- redefining library functions to try and optimise them is futile and risky.

Comment: We cannot use that functions, we are only allow to use write, malloc and free basically, and we read one character per read call, so thats why its cost more with a big string. But great answer! Can you explain me about your strlen? honestly, I don't understand nothing on that, lol , too deep for me

Comment: @rogertaht: The pastebin does not contain the complete code to a compilable program because utility functions such as `ft_strlen`, `ft_strchr` , `ft_strnew`, `ft_strjoin`and `ft_strncpy` are missing. Furthermore, is this your code or school libraries? The code is too complicated. Maintaining hidden static state such as `static t_list *l_files;` must be avoided: what if the file read through `fd` is closed and another one is opened, receiving the same handle, the static list will provide erroneous data.

Comment: The coding style looks like that enforced at Epitech or 42, IMHO not very readable, nor promoting the best practices, such as favoring `while` over `for` loops... It is a fine and valuable exercise to rewrite the C library functions from scratch, but correctness and simplicity must be the first goal.